# How to convert an Avro data file to CSV

Tags: csv, hadoop, avro

I have an avro data file and I need to convert it to a csv file. Avro totext tool currently doesn't support  the use of a custom schema. Are there any tools out there that do this? Would I just have to code it up using avro tools?

Comment: Avro buffer could be a complex data, why do you need it in csv form. JSON is preferable.

Comment: Whether or not avro is capable of storing more complex data is totally irrelevant: you sometimes need data in other formats.

Answer (score 2):

I asked the same question and I just used Spark API to get this done:

Read the data as:

```
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val avro = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load("/path/to/your/data")
```

or

```
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val avro = sqlContext.avroFile("/path/to/your/data")
```

And then you can do something like:

```
val csv = avro.map(_.mkString(","))
```

And then to see the results, you can check this out running something like:

```
csv.take(2).foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//Spark2.0 +   
    import com.databricks.spark.avro._

    //Read avro file
    val df = spark.read.avro("/FileStore/tables/279ltrs61490238208016/twitter.avro")
    df.printSchema()
    df.count()
    df.show()


    //Write to csv file
    df.write
      .option("header", "true")
      .csv("/FileStore/tables/279ltrs61490238208016/twitter_out.csv")

    //Read csv file and display contents
    val df1 = spark.read.option("header", true).csv("/FileStore/tables/279ltrs61490238208016/twitter_out.csv")
    df1.count()
    df1.printSchema()
    df1.show()
    df1.count()
```

Comment: Start spark shell using `spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:4.0.0`. Found it at https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro#with-spark-shell-or-spark-submit

Answer (score 0):

There are simple CSV encoder and decoders for avro implementing the avro Encoder and Decoder interfaces in the [spf4j-avro](http://www.spf4j.org/spf4j-avro-components/spf4j-avro/index.html) library. (just like the available implementations binary and json). the Csv Encoder/Decoders will Encode/Decode from/to csv as long as your schema conforms to array where record cannot have array and map field types.

The code is at [csv](https://github.com/zolyfarkas/spf4j/tree/master/spf4j-avro-components/spf4j-avro/src/main/java/org/spf4j/avro/csv). If you want to see how you can leverage it, there is an example on how you can implement a JAX-RS MessageBody(Reader/Writer) [at](https://github.com/zolyfarkas/spf4j-jaxrs/blob/master/spf4j-jaxrs-client/src/main/java/org/spf4j/jaxrs/common/avro/CsvAvroMessageBodyWriter.java).

Answer (score -1):

there is also this converter of avro files to csv online, it was already useful to me https://avro-tools.com/avro-viewer-and-converter-to-json-and-csv, and another way that I know is through Spark https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-avro .html but it is a solution that requires programming in that Framework.